# Kubernetes get container image url

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to identify the url from where container executing in Kubernetes POD was pulled from ?

The Kubernetes Image [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/) indicate only image name is provided as part of Pod specification.

I would like to identify if image was pulled from Google Container Registry, Amazon ECR, IBM Cloud Container Registry etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the image id to understand that. Something like

```
kubectl get pod pod-name-123 -o json | jq '.status.containerStatuses[] | .imageID'
```

will return something like:

```
"docker-pullable://redacted.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/docker-image-name@sha256:redacted"
```

In my example was pulled from aws ecr.